# How to Preserve Image URLs When Exporting Data from One Strapi Instance to Another?

Tags: json, strapi, data-import, data-export

I'm working on a project where I need to sync content between production and local development environments in Strapi. My approach involves exporting data from production to JSON and then importing it into my local instance. This process works well for textual content **but fails for images due to the direct URLs and asset IDs in the JSON pointing to the production environment's media library**.

For example, after export, I have a JSON entry like this:

```json
"plugin::upload.file": {
  "6": {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "amit.png",
    "url": "/uploads/amit_b1eb7b0b8b.png"
  }
}
```

But when imported into the local environment, I encounter errors due to non-existing asset IDs and irrelevant URLs:

```
Error: {
  "code": "ERR_INVALID_URL",
  "input": "/uploads/amit_f818a27755.png",
  "level": "error"
}
```

Both environments have identical media structure (e.g., a "banners" folder with images). How can I correctly import the media files so that the URLs are valid in the target environment?

Comment: How do you export/import your content?
Are you using a specific Strapi plugin or command line? Directly from the database tool you use? If yes what is the databaseyou use?